# asm/types.h Error during compilation of ebpf code

Tags: clang, ebpf, xdp-bpf, bcc-bpf

Here i am trying to compile a eBPF code. and used the following command for compilation.
command: clang -O2 -target bpf -c your_ebpf_program.c -o your_ebpf_program.o

error: In file included from my_program.c:2:/usr/include/linux/bpf.h:11:10: fatal error: 'asm/types.h' file not found#include <asm/types.h>         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~1 error generated.

I used clang as a compiler for compilation. All the required libraries are downloaded and yet got an error stating asm/types.h is not found. All the linux header files are updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to install additional kernel headers. On Ubuntu for example you can do so by executing

```
apt install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Apparently on some platforms you might need to symlink a directory as well. But I am not sure that is always required. [Source 1](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/3731) [Source 2](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/4253)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm /usr/include/asm
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to install Libbpf:

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt-get -y install libbpf-dev
```